# Does const ref lvalue to non-const func return value specifically reduce copies?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I have encountered a C++ habit that I have tried to research in order to understand its impact and validate its usage. But I can't seem to find the exact answer.

```
std::vector< Thing > getThings();

void do() {
    const std::vector< Thing > &things = getThings();   
}
```

Here we have some function that returns a non-`const&` value. The habit I am seeing is the usage of a `const&` lvalue when assigning the return value from the function. The proposed reasoning for this habit is that it reduces a copy.

Now I have been researching RVO (Return Value Optimization), copy elision, and C++11 move semantics. I realize that a given compiler could choose to prevent a copy via RVO **regardless** of the use of `const&` here. But does the usage of a `const&` lvalue here have any kind of effect on non-`const&` return values in terms of preventing copies? And I am specifically asking about pre-C++11 compilers, **before** move semantics.

My assumption is that either the compiler implements RVO or it does not, and that saying the lvalue should be `const&` doesn't hint or force a copy-free situation.

**Edit**

I am specifically asking about whether `const&` usage here reduces a copy, and not about the lifetime of the temporary object, as described in ["the most important const"](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)

**Further clarification of question**

Is this:

```
const std::vector< Thing > &things = getThings();
```

any different than this:

```
std::vector< Thing > things = getThings();
```

**in terms of reducing copies**? Or does it not have any influence on whether the compiler can reduce copies, such as via RVO?

Comment: @Nawaz, I saw this article as well, but I was thrown by the use of a string literal. Does this actually apply exactly to my example, where you build up a vector on the stack and return it? Does this mean the vector is not copied?

Comment: If you've read that, then you should understand the *bottomline* of the argument presented in the article is that **if a `const` reference binds to a temporary, then the lifetime of the temporary is extended till the scope of the reference, and it is irrespective of the type of the object.** Also, the function in the article does NOT return *string literal*, it returns a `std:string` (which is constructed from a string literal, but that does not matter).

Comment: Sounds like you should have referenced this article and your description as the answer to my question instead of suggesting it as a dup :-)

Comment: It is guaranteed that binding a reference to a value of the same type (ignoring const-qualifiers), does not copy the value

Comment: Thanks, @M.M. I realize that it does not copy the value. But what I am asking is if it **prevents** a copy that would otherwise happen in that return value if you had left it off... As in, something that I thought RVO handles. I'm trying to qualify whether the usage of the `const&` actually adds the value of preventing a copy that would otherwise actually occur.

Comment: @jdi: semantically, there are two copies usually involved, but in this case, there is only copy (inside the function at the return statement, which is still there semantically, but can be elided by language); the *other* copy (at the call site) is not even allowed semantically because the target is a `const&`.

Comment: @jdi i'm not sure if "prevent" and "otherwise" are the right word. You're implying comparison between two cases but you didn't say what you are comparing against. I guess you mean `T x = y()`.  But `T x = y();` and `T const &x = y();` are two different pieces of code that have different effects and requirements. The first one might have more copies than the second one, depending on whether the compiler opts to use copy elision.

Comment: @M.M, ok I am reading [Copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and I see this for pre-c++11: 
"When a nameless temporary, not bound to any references, would be moved or copied into an object of the same type (...), the copy/move is omitted. When that temporary is constructed, it is constructed directly in the storage where it would otherwise be moved or copied to. When the nameless temporary is the argument of a return statement, this variant of copy elision is known as RVO, "return value optimization"."
Does this mean the `&` part of the lvalue doesn't matter?

Comment: @jdi sorry but "Does this mean the & part of the lvalue doesn't matter?" doesn't make any sense

Comment: @jdi: I've edited my answer. Please see it and let me know if that answers your question completely.

Comment: @M.M, what I mean is that the way I read that description, it seems to mean that as long as its the same type as the nameless temporary, that NRVO or RVO can occur. It doesn't say anything about it needing to be a `const&` lvalue, which is the focus of my question. I still feel like this implies that it can happen without the "help" of saying  `const std::vector<Thing> &thing = getThings()`. It seems to say you could just do this `std::vector<Thing> thing = getThings() ` and if the compiler supports RVO, then it will happen.

Comment: Seems unclear what you are asking: your question appears to be  clearly asking whether `T const &x = y();` means that the return value is not copied, but people have answered this and then you say that you do realize it is not copied already and seem to be asking something else.

Comment: you keep saying "lvalue" in a context where "lvalue" doesn't make sense and I don't know what you're trying to say. An lvalue is a category of expression. An "lvalue reference" is part of a type.   Can you try editing your question to be more clear about what you are asking about (including two pieces of code if you are asking about the difference between two pieces of code).

Comment: Re. the edit you just made: the question has been answered already (by my earlier comment and Nawaz): yes, the `const &` version guarantees no copy of the return value, and the other version might have copies.

Comment: @jdi: I think your edit is clearly answered by my answer. Are you asking `int const & x= i;` does make copy? No, it does NOT. It is not because the compiler optimizes it, it is because the language does NOT allow copy here. (assume `i` to be `int`). Now replace `i` with a call: `int const & x = j();`. Now at the call site *the same* story is there; the new story that pops up is related to the `return` statement, which is a copy *semantically speaking* which can be elided. (assume `f` to be `int f()`).

Comment: Thanks for the patience, @M.M and Nawaz. Sorry if my question ended up being vague even though I tried my best to be specific.

Comment: As convention the ref-to-const makes the code **brittle**, because with maintenance of the code it might be bound to a reference result that becomes invalid a line or two down in the code. To find out if it buys you anything, *measure*. Most likely it doesn't improve efficiency at all: it's just a way to introduce some brittleness that is obscure and verbose to boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey so your question is:

"When a function returns a class instance by value, and you assign it to a const reference, does that avoid a copy constructor call?"

Ignoring the lifetime of the temporary, as that’s not the question you’re asking, we can get a feel for what happens by looking at the assembly output. I’m using clang, llvm 7.0.2.

Here’s something box standard. Return by value, nothing fancy.

**Test A**

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(const MyClass & source);
    long int m_tmp;
};

MyClass createMyClass();

int main()
{
    const MyClass myClass = createMyClass();
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile with “-O0 -S -fno-elide-constructors” I get this.

```
_main:
    pushq   %rbp                    # Boiler plate
    movq    %rsp, %rbp              # Boiler plate
    subq    $32, %rsp               # Reserve 32 bytes for stack frame
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rdi         # arg0 = &___temp_items = rdi = rbp-24
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)            # rbp-4 = 0, no idea why this happens
    callq   __Z13createMyClassv     # createMyClass(arg0)
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rdi         # arg0 = & myClass
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rsi         # arg1 = &__temp_items
    callq   __ZN7MyClassC1ERKS_     # MyClass::MyClass(arg0, arg1)
    xorl    %eax, %eax              # eax = 0, the return value for main
    addq    $32, %rsp               # Pop stack frame
    popq    %rbp                    # Boiler plate
    retq
```

We are looking at only the calling code. We’re not interested in the implementation of createMyClass. That’s compiled somewhere else.
So createMyClass creates the class inside a temporary and then that gets copied into myClass.

Simples.

What about the const ref version ?

**Test B**

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(const MyClass & source);
    long int m_tmp;
};

MyClass createMyClass();

int main()
{
    const MyClass & myClass = createMyClass();
    return 0;
}
```

Same compiler options.

```
_main:                              # Boiler plate
    pushq   %rbp                    # Boiler plate
    movq    %rsp, %rbp              # Boiler plate
    subq    $32, %rsp               # Reserve 32 bytes for the stack frame
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rdi         # arg0 = &___temp_items = rdi = rbp-24
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)            # *(rbp-4) = 0, no idea what this is for
    callq   __Z13createMyClassv     # createMyClass(arg0)
    xorl    %eax, %eax              # eax = 0, the return value for main
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rdi         # rdi = &___temp_items
    movq    %rdi, -16(%rbp)         # &myClass = rdi = &___temp_items;
    addq    $32, %rsp               # Pop stack frame
    popq    %rbp                    # Boiler plate
    retq
```

No copy constructor and therefore more optimal right ?

What happens if we turn off “-fno-elide-constructors” for both versions? Still keeping -O0.

**Test A**

```
_main:
    pushq   %rbp                    # Boiler plate
    movq    %rsp, %rbp              # Boiler plate
    subq    $16, %rsp               # Reserve 16 bytes for the stack frame
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rdi         # arg0 = &myClass = rdi = rbp-16
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)            # rbp-4 = 0, no idea what this is
    callq   __Z13createMyClassv     # createMyClass(arg0)
    xorl    %eax, %eax              # eax = 0, return value for main
    addq    $16, %rsp               # Pop stack frame
    popq    %rbp                    # Boiler plate
    retq
```

Clang has removed the copy constructor call.

**Test B**

```
_main:                              # Boiler plate
    pushq   %rbp                    # Boiler plate
    movq    %rsp, %rbp              # Boiler plate
    subq    $32, %rsp               # Reserve 32 bytes for the stack frame
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rdi         # arg0 = &___temp_items = rdi = rbp-24
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)            # rbp-4 = 0, no idea what this is
    callq   __Z13createMyClassv     # createMyClass(arg0)
    xorl    %eax, %eax              # eax = 0, return value for main
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rdi         # rdi = &__temp_items
    movq    %rdi, -16(%rbp)         # &myClass = rdi
    addq    $32, %rsp               # Pop stack frame
    popq    %rbp                    # Boiler plate
    retq
```

Test B (assign to const reference) is the same as it was before.  It now has more instructions than Test A.

What if we set optimisation to -O1 ?

```
_main:
    pushq   %rbp                    # Boiler plate
    movq    %rsp, %rbp              # Boiler plate
    subq    $16, %rsp               # Reserve 16 bytes for the stack frame
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rdi          # arg0 = &___temp_items = rdi = rbp-8
    callq   __Z13createMyClassv     # createMyClass(arg0)
    xorl    %eax, %eax              # ex = 0, return value for main
    addq    $16, %rsp               # Pop stack frame
    popq    %rbp                    # Boiler plate
    retq
```

Both source files turn into this when compiled with -O1.
They result in exactly the same assembler.
This is also true for -O4.

The compiler doesn’t know about the contents of createMyClass so it can’t do anything more to optimise.

With the compiler I'm using, you get no performance gain from assigning to a const ref.

I imagine it's a similar situation for g++ and intel although it's always good to check.

Comment: This is awesome and directly speaks to my question, as opposed to talking about lifetimes. I really appreciate the specific proofs provided and breaking down the meaning of the assembly output!

Comment: Note that what machine instructions are emitted by the compiler is NOT what *required* by the language specification, rather it is a summation of  *what is required by the specification* + *what is allowed (but not required) by the specification* . So it is because of the latter, different compilers *could produce different* machine instructions and still be *conformant* to the language specification.

Comment: @Nawaz, sure I get what you are saying. It comes down to whether one wants to consider what is common in practice on modern compilers vs what the language spec guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

Semantically, the compiler needs an *accessible* copy-constructor, at the call site, even if later on, the compiler elides the call to the copy-constructor — that optimization is done later in the compilation phase after the semantic-analysis phase.

After reading your comments, I think I understand your question better. Now let me answer it in detail.

Imagine that the function has this return statement:

```
return items;
```

Semantically speaking, the compiler *needs* an accessible copy-constructor (or move-constructor) here, which can be  elided. However, just for the sake of argument, assume that it makes a copy here and the copy is stored in `__temp_items` which I expressed this as:

```
__temp_items <= return items; //first copy:
```

Now at the call site, assume that you have not used `const &`, so it becomes this:

```
std::vector<Thing> things = __temp_items;  //second copy
```

Now as you can see yourself, there are two copies. Compilers are allowed to elide both of them.

However, your actual code uses `const &`, so it becomes this:

```
const std::vector<Thing> & things = __temp_items;  //no copy anymore.
```

Now, semantically there is only one copy, which can still be elided by the compiler. As for the second copy, I wont say `const&` *"prevented"* it in the sense that compiler has optimised it, rather it is not allowed by the language to begin with.

---

But interestingly, no matter how many times the compiler makes copies while returning, or elides few (or all) of them, the return value **is** a *temporary*. If that is so, then how does binding to a temporary work? If that is also your question *(now I know that is not your question but then keep it that way so that I dont have to erase this part of my answer)*, then yes it works and that is guaranteed by the language.

As explained in the article [`the most imporant const`](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) in very detail, that if a `const` reference binds to a temporary, then the lifetime of the temporary is extended till the scope of the reference, *and it is irrespective of the type of the object*.

In C++11, there is another way to extend the lifetime of a temporary, which is rvalue-reference:

```
std::vector<Thing> && things = getThings();
```

It has the same effect, but the advantage (or *disadvantage* — depends on the context) is that you can also modify the content.

I personally prefer to write this as:

```
auto && things = getThings();
```

but then that is not *necessarily* a rvalue-reference — if you change the  return type of the function, to return a reference, then `things` turns out to bind to lvalue-reference. If you want to discuss that, then that is a whole different topic.

Comment: Lower down in the comments of that link, there is this: "The point being that according to the standard, when assigning an rvalue to a const reference, the compiler is allowed to make a copy of the rvalue.

So, whether or not the compiler avails itself of this, the copy constructor must be accesible."
Does this mean you are not guaranteed there is not going to be a copy anyways?

Comment: @jdi: those are semantical issues. the point is that no matter how many times the compiler make copies while returning, or elide few of them, the return value **is** a *temporary*; that is the only concern here, as far as lifetime is concern. And yes, if the copy-constructor is *inaccesible* (say it is declared `private`), then your code would NOT compile to begin with. Hope that clarifies your doubt.

Comment: But my question was specifically about preventing a copy by the use of `const&` and not about the lifetime of the resulting temporary. Is this answer still correct, given that?

Comment: Alright. I didn't understand your question. Let me edit my answer to include this as well.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer, and even including information that isn't part of my question. Although I still have to ask... is the ultimate answer you are giving to my question "No, using const& does not prevent a copy"?

Comment: @Nawaz "but then that is not necessarily a rvalue-reference" -- well, technically, it is an rvalue-reference-typed declaration, it's just that reference collapsing for rvalue references preserves lvalue references: `&& &` -> `&`

Comment: @jdi: practically, it does, but from the language point of view, it does not give any gaurantee.

Comment: @oldrinb: What is *"rvalue reference type declaration"*? I think you meant *forwarding reference*? That is a new term introduced by C++14, and that does not *necessarily* mean *rvalue reference*.

Comment: fair game, that is correct; iirc in C++11 `T&&` was used as what-is-now a forwarding reference type but simply called a rvalue reference type, which the new nomenclature in C++14 addresses

Comment: @oldrinb: Even before it was not called rvalue-reference (those called it so is because of their lack of understanding of the language). However, Scott Meyers had invented a term called *universal reference* for it, which now has been replaced by *forwarding-reference*.

Comment: Your latest updates do seem to answer my question. What I get from reading it is that in a modern compiler, using `const&` is not necc reducing the effective copies. Only reducing the number of copies the compiler would elide.